# mysql auto increment without inserting

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with an auto increment field. I am using the auto increment counter as an id generator across the database.

I need a way to increment the counter, get the new number but without inserting any data.

Is there an easy to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you are using the auto increment counter as an "ID generator across the database"?

Comment: @Daan I use the ids from that table as primary keys on other tables

Comment: What exactly is your use case, if you don't mind sharing? I can't imagine there isn't a better way to do whatever it is you want to do without using the auto increment counter and rollbacks :)

Comment: @Daan it's a table with raw data. The data is then taken out, cleaned up and placed in other tables. I want the id to be unique amongst those tables. I now need to insert some data directly into the "clean" tables and need to generate an id.

Comment: Ah. Yes, in that case you'd need to do something like this if you can't insert any data. Thanks for clearing this up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using it as an ID generator, then (aside from altering the table) you'll have to insert something to get the next value.

The easiest way to do this without inserting any data would be to do an `INSERT` followed by calling `LAST_INSERT_ID` followed by issuing a `ROLLBACK`.  That will rollback the insert, but the next ID will still be incremented.

Comment: Actually, using a `blackhole` engine would be the easiest if I'm not mistaken :)

Comment: ROLLBACK is possible only if storage engine is InnoDB.I think he can issue DELETE FROM after LAST_INSERT_ID.This will be more generic way.

Comment: @N.B. - It would seem so, but the blackhole engine doesn't maintain the state of the auto_increment value, so although you can put one on a blackhole table, they are kind of worthless.

Comment: Sounds good. So if I insert, get last_insert_id and it's `100` then rollback. the next time I insert in the db, the row will get an id of `101`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to alter table so you can use this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = id+1
```

here id will be your auto-increment field.
But Auto-increment fields are incremented with respect to the max value in that column.

Comment: Note: Doing an alter table is *not* transactional in mysql. Any existing transactions will be committed by altering the table, as such this is not a recommended way to do it.